# customize shipping price of the product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

we need some requirement regarding  shipping information :-

Eg we have purchased 1 pen then shipping add $15  one product.

other customer wholesaler  have purchased  400 pen shipping added 400*15 
but my question 400 open pack in box and round tape  how to calculate box weight and how price include or not please confirm how can manage in magento

Answer (score 0):

you can use table rate wight vs destination

or flat rate per order as your order has wrapped in one pack consider per order

or else add one more option for table rate,  #item row vs destination based on number of row apply price

i hope this will solve your situations